# CPP Function param use function with multi params

Tags: functions, cpp

I want to specify a function with parameters for a function parameter, but it doesn't come together.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Example funch...
void fileLoad(String path, String type) {
  file = SD.open(path.c_str(), FILE_READ);
  server.streamFile(file, type) != file.size();
  file.close();
}

// This is how I want to use it, but it's not possible:
server.on("/homepage", fileLoad("app/homepage.html", "text/html") );

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Currently, as it works, you need 1 extra funch...:
void homepage() {
  fileLoad("app/homepage.html", "text/html");
}
server.on("/homepage", homepage);
```

Comment: How you want it isn't how C++ works. Depending on how "on" is written, and what you're actually using, you *might* be able to use a lambda, or you could start playing C++ games a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/41528436/438992. But I wouldn't.

Comment: @DaveNewton, it [does support](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/src/ESP8266WebServer.h#L94) `std::function` and so lambdas of the type that would be needed, so you could make that an answer.

Comment: @timemage I don't remember enough C++ to be coherent ;)

Comment: Well, I need more coffee, but I took a stab at it anyway. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [examples of this sort of thing](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/PathArgServer/PathArgServer.ino) in the library's examples.

The `on()` function [does support](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/src/ESP8266WebServer.h#L94) [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as a parameter, which in turn, means you can use a C++11-onwards [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (which [Dave Newton](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/8583/dave-newton) mentioned in comments) to proxy your two-argument function call through a no-argument function:

```cpp
server.on("/homepage", [] () {
    fileLoad("app/homepage.html", "text/html");
});
```

The [] ("capture list") is something that would be used if you wanted to copy or refer to things within the scope of the `on` function call.  Since you're not doing that you could also just write a no-argument function which turns around and calls `fileLoad` with your two compile-time-known values.  But it is common for people using this webserver library to need to make references things in scope.

---

As as side note, I'd consider *not* using `String` as your received parameter type in `void fileLoad(String path, String type)`.  When passing in a string literal, you're just causing dynamic allocation for no particularly good reason.

Comment: Thank you!!! :)